# ldap virtual attribute for full names

Tags: attributes, ldap, mapping, virtual, openldap

I have user objects in LDAP which has these to attributes: givenName,lastName.
For some applications I need an attribute which shows the full name.

How can I get this work with virtual attributes? SLAPO-RWM seems only to map single attributes.

---

givenName=Test
lastName=Tus

Should create a virtual attribute fullName="Test Tus".

Answer (score 1):

CommonName (cn) is the attribute generally used to store the full name.